# XPath: "Exclude" tag in "InnerHtml" (<a href="">InnerHtml<span>excludeme</span></a>

Tags: html, xpath, screen-scraping

I am using XPath to query HTML sites, which works pretty good so far, but now I hit a (brick)wall and can't find a solution :-)

The html looks like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="">Text1<span>AnotherText1</span></a></li>
<li><a href="">Text2<span>AnotherText2</span></a></li>
<li><a href="">Text3<span>AnotherText3</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to select the "TextX" part, but NOT the AnotherTextX part in the `<span></span>`
So far I couldn't come up with any (pure) XPath solution to do that (and in my setup I unfortunately need a pure XPath solution.

This selects kind of what I want, but it results in "TextXAnotherTextX" and I only need "TextX".

```
/ul/li/a
```

Any hints? :-)

Comment: Hi! You should accept/up-vote answers that helped you solve your problem. Thanks! :)

Comment: done. sorry. not really familiar with Stack Overflow (yet) :-)

Comment: Well, welcome on board. ;-) Thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets you the first direct text node child of `<a>`:

```
/ul/li/a/text()[1]
```

and this would get you *any* direct text node child (separately):

```
/ul/li/a/text()
```

Both of the above return `"TextX"`, but if you had:

```
<li><a href="">Text4<span>AnotherText3</span>TrailingText</a></li>
```

then the latter would return: `["Text4", "TrailingText"]`, while the former would return `"Text4"` only.

Your expression `/ul/li/a` gets the string value of `<a>`, which is defined as the concatenation of the string value of all the children of `<a>`, so you get `"TextXAnotherTextX"`.

Comment: Thanks for your very helpful response!
I've been searching the web for days! :-)
Stack Overflow is really VERY good!