# Scala get text from element without child element

Tags: html, scala, xpath

From HTML like following I would like to get only text in `<p>` without text, that are in `<span>` element:

```
<p>Text I want <span class="orange_font inner_subtitle">Some text</span></p>
```

This code now returns text also in `<span>` element, how this can be avoided?

```
 val result: WebElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='container']/p/span")))
    result.getText()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath: "Exclude" tag in "InnerHtml" (<a href="">InnerHtml<span>excludeme</span></a>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458459/xpath-exclude-tag-in-innerhtml-a-href-innerhtmlspanexcludeme-span)

Answer (score 0):

For the full text without `<span>` html element: `By.xpath("string(//*[@id='container']/p)")`

For just the `<p>` tag text without the `<span>` content `By.xpath("//*[@id='container']/p/text()")`